# Inverse limit of isomorphic objects

Tags: category-theory

Is the inverse limit of isomorphic objects isomorphic to each one of them?

I know there is this question:

[inverse limit of isomorphic vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9875/inverse-limit-of-isomorphic-vector-spaces)

but it seems that there they have a total order  (not only a partial one) and distinguished morphisms.

---

In particular, I'm instersted in the case of the category of groups

---

**Edition made:** The original question was why that fact was true, but as it seems to be needed some connectivity hypothesis I've changed the question in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: You need that the functions inside the inverse limit are isomorphisms. For example, the inverse limit of $G_n=\mathbb Z$ under the maps $G_n\to G_{n-1}$ being $k\mapsto nk$ has inverse limit $\{0\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok, thanks. And if I have that these arrows are isomorphisms, what I must do?

Comment: Also, technically, a cartesian product is an inverse limit, one with no maps. So what you need is (1) that the category $I$ is non-empty and "connected," and the functor $F: I\to C$ has the property that $Ff$ is an isomorphism for every map $f$ in $I$.  Then the inverse limit exists and is isomorphic to any of the individual $FX$ for some object $X$ in $I$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, but.. who are F, I and C?

Comment: I assumed, since you labeled this with category theory, that you were talking about category-theory inverse limits. The inverse limit is defined for functors $F$ from a small category $\mathcal I$ and a destination category $\mathcal C$. Sometimes, Perhaps you are using some other definition based on directed sets?

Comment: No, I'm using the regular definition, but I don't see what are you saying. I'll think about your previous comment. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, you haven't said what you mean by "the regular definition." Anyway, if you aren't using the broader definition, better to ignore my comments.

Comment: haha you are right, with regular definition I wanted to refer to the  first definition that you said.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, you need a bit more than connectivity here. Consider the equaliser of two _different_ isomorphisms. I suspect you need a _simply connected_ diagram.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what do you mean by $G_n $?